# How to set write timeout on Socket

Tags: java, sockets

In java, Socket has a method `setSoTimeout` that can be used to specify the `reading` timeout, but there is no method to specify the `writing` timeout

When I　searched google, a lot of responses like "`use nio and selectors`", it looks that `SocketChannel` provides the way to specify the `writing` timeout, I brief the code of this class, but I still didn't find out how to do it.

Could someone show some code or some guide? Thanks

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338885/java-socket-output-stream-writes-do-they-block

Comment: Thanks @PrashantPuri. yes, the link has mentioned `use nio and selectors`,but didn't say how.

Comment: He most certainly did say how, or rather provided a [link](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4031100) to how.

Comment: @EJP which link, sorry I didn't find the link. 
 http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4031100?

Comment: @Tom That link. The one he provided. The one I provided. The one you put in your most recent comment.

Comment: ok, thank you @ejp,

Comment: Baffling really.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to mitigate the lack of a timeout option on a write call is to simply just set the `SO_SNDBUF` size via `Socket.setSendBuffer` to something very high. This will allow subsequent calls for writing to avoid blocking unless the pipe to the remote side gets backed up. If possible, structure your protocol such that you wait for some sort of response to data already sent before sending more data. That way, you won't ever exceed the send buffer.

YMMV.